# How to plot multiple graphs using values from rows of CSV file one by one,

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested-loops

I am new to R. I have a file with 92 rows and 6 columns. I have to plot 92 graphs of a Equation (water retention) getting 4 values (Theta_r,theta_s,alpha,n, m=1-1/n) from each row one by one from CSV file.

I have plotted a graph for this equation simply with some given values

[image: 1]

with the following code.

```
library(ggplot2)
x<- seq(0,6,0.1)
cbind(x)
log<- 10^x
tht_s <- 0.4
tht_r <- 0
alpha<- 0.1
n<- 1.3
m<- 0.2308
theta<- tht_r + (tht_s- tht_r) * (1+(alpha*log)^n)^-m
dat<- data.frame(x,theta)
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = dat , aes(x=x, y=theta)) + 
  ylab ("water content (cm3 cm-3)")`
```

but this time R should take values from CSV file's rows one by one and generate 92 graphs. I tried with loop for (i 1:92) but I get error may be because variable "log" has around 60 values (that are for the points to plot graph)

> Error in data.frame(x, theta) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 61, 92
>
> In alpha * log :longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

and I can't figure out how to make R take values from rows one by one using loop. I have tried many approaches and seen many youtube videos but couldn't figure out.

I need to save these graphs 10x2 on single sheet.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! The error messages point you to the issues: `x` has 61 elements while `theta` has 92 so you cannot create the data.frame. Also, the length of `alpha` is not a multiple of the length of `log`, so R can't multiply. How does your loop look like? A [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for reply
yes this is problem I am getting because I think I didnt use proper loop. In my simple code you must have seen theta was using 61 Log values and generating 61 values but its not in this new case.
Could you please help me with loop (for or nested) how can I use here and how to read values row by row and putting in the equation
would be appreciated

Comment: Would be helpful if you would post your loop then.